# My variable does not seem to be available in blade view

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My Route...

```
   Route::get('/test', function () {

    $word = ['Hello'];



    return view('test', $word);
});
```

My Blade View...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Laravel Quickstart - Basic</title>
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/Test.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- CSS And JavaScript -->
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        {{$word}}
    </nav>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I get the following erro when accessing the app via a browser...

> (2/2) ErrorException Undefined variable: word (View:
>   /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/resources/views/test.blade.php)

When I remove $word form the blade view and replace with a static string "test" it displays correctly.

no idea why the blade view can't see the $word varible,  any ideas anyone?

Comment: use this:- `return view('test', ['word' => $word]);` . now you can access it by `{{ $word }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return it to the view in one of two ways:

```
return view('test', compact('word'));
```

Or

```
return view('test', ['word' => $word]);
```

Either of these methods will then enable you to use the $word variable from within the blade file

You can see an example of this within the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
return view('test', $word);
```

To

```
return view('test', compact('word'));
```

The variable will be available in your blade.

Answer (score 1):

To complete Karl's answer, you can see an example there : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#creating-views

Comment: While this may answer the question, 
[it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the 
essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.